# Run-time Error 3131 Syntax Error in FROM clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Tried scouring the forums for threads similar to mine but couldn't really find anything that would lead me in the right direction. Basically I have a table that has the QA scores for each of the 10 regions and I am trying to populate a text box with a specific region's score depending on the month. I was trying to do this in vba for this form but came across this Run-time error 3131 and I'm not entirely sure what's wrong with my code which seems simple enough to me. Thanks for any help or advice in advance.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()


Dim strSql As String


strSql = "SELECT tblScorecard.[QA_Overall]" & _
        "FROM tblScorecard" & _
        "WHERE tblScorecard.[Audit Month] = 'Jan'" & _
        "AND tblScorecard.[Region] = '1'"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSql

txtReg1 = strSql

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not possible you should just add spaces?
tblScorecard.[QA_Overall]FROM as one word?

```
Private Sub Form_Load()


Dim strSql As String


strSql = "SELECT tblScorecard.[QA_Overall] " & _
        "FROM tblScorecard " & _
        "WHERE tblScorecard.[Audit Month] = 'Jan'" & _
        " AND tblScorecard.[Region] = '1'"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSql

txtReg1 = strSql

End Sub
```

In order to avoid  Error: 2342 A RunSQL:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    strSql = "SELECT tblScorecard.[QA_Overall] " & _
        "FROM tblScorecard " & _
        "WHERE tblScorecard.[Audit Month] = 'Jan'" & _
        " AND tblScorecard.[Region] = '1'"
    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "tempQry"
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("tempQry", strSQL)
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("tempQry")
End Sub
```

More information found [here](http://access-excel.tips/access-docmd-runsql-error-2342/).

Comment: It's not the `[QA_Overall]FROM` that's the problem, it's the `FROM tblScorecardWHERE`

Comment: Added a space on the previous line. I think both were a problem here.

Comment: So the code to avoid error 2342 works and creates the tempQry. Would using DLookUp interfere with this if i'm going to be repeating this code again for the other text boxes?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `& _`, you are not adding a line beak INSIDE the string

Try adding a space at the end of the strings

```
strSql = "SELECT tblScorecard.[QA_Overall] " & _
        "FROM tblScorecard " & _
        "WHERE tblScorecard.[Audit Month] = 'Jan' " & _
        "AND tblScorecard.[Region] = '1'"
```

Comment: oh dur lol. well that seemed to fix it but it throws me a 2342 A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement. I'm not sure how what I wrote isn't sql?